# Java - Won't display a black screen

Tags: java, graphics, colors

My Java program won't display a black screen when I tell it to. I can just see a greyish window with 0 FPS.

Here is my code:

```
package com.none.rain;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    private boolean running = false;
    private JFrame frame;
    private Thread thread;

    public Game() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width*scale, height*scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        frame = new JFrame();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {

        }
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle("Rain");
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the display black is something you do in your `render()` method, but you never call it.

If I take your code and add a call to `render()` in the `run()` method I get a frame with a black background:

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, totaly forgot to add that! Thanks!